# Macro resolution

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro that resolves to a string which contains an ampersand and this cause the error `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference A not resolved`.

For example

```
Data _NULL_;
T=%NRSTR("A&A");
call symput("test",T);
run;

%put &=test.;
```

Is there a way to only resolve only once? The NR function seems to remove the meaning of all `&` and prevent any resolutions. I only want it to be resolved once.

The following example works but I need it to be part of a data step as there are several other regex functions that are being used to create the `A&A`string.

```
%let Test=%NRSTR(A&A);
%put &test;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DATA step single quote the text value that is being sent to the macro environment.

To prevent the `&` from being interpreted as a resolution request, `%superq` the macro symbol when using it.

```
Data _NULL_;
  T = 'A&A';
  call symput("test",T);
run;

%put NOTE: test macro symbol value is %superq(test);

---------- LOG ----------
21   %put NOTE: test macro symbol value is %superq(test);
NOTE: test macro symbol value is A&A
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with the first usage just use single quotes. This will allow you create the macro variable with the ampersand in it.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('test','A&A');
run;
```

Then use some macro code to add macro quoting. I find %SUPERQ() the easiest.

```
%let test=%superq(test);
```

If you are making a lot of macro variables in this way in the same data step you might want to use the RESOLVE() or CALL EXECUTE() function to allow you to run the %LET right after you create the macro variable.

```
data _null_;
  set variable_list;
  call symputx(name,value);
  call execute(catx(' ','%let',name,'=%superq(',name,');'));
run;
```